# Meaning of "She was a girl who for a ringing phone dropped exactly nothing"

Tags: meaning, idioms, sentence

Can you tell me what the following means?

> She was a girl who for a ringing phone dropped exactly nothing.

Comment: Clearly the girl has grown tired of telemarketers trying to sell her new aluminum siding and offer her low rates on weekend getaways to the Bahamas. How many years ago was this sentence written? It's acquired new meaning in this the robo-caller age. Used to be phone calls were *important*, now they're likely to be junk mail.

Comment: You should have explained "what" you didn't understand and included a reference. Better questions than yours have been closed in the past because they didn't contain research or enough information. Janus's answer is excellent but it is carsmack's post which has clarified the phrase's real meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed, and IMO a lot of that should have been edited into the question rather than included (only) as an answer.

Answer (score 35):

It’s a partially inverted sentence, with the prepositional phrase *for a ringing phone* moved further up in the sentence for emphasis. In a more neutral word order, it would be:

> She was a girl who dropped exactly nothing for a ringing phone.

The deeper meaning of ‘dropping’ something is that when the phone rings, you are (or perhaps rather: you used to be) expected to drop (= stop) everything you were doing and rush over to pick up the phone.

This girl who drops nothing to do so, basically just observes that the phone is ringing, but doesn’t let it distract her from what she is doing. Maybe she just let it ring until it finished; maybe she waited until it suited her and then went to pick up the phone—that’s not clear. But she certainly didn’t drop what was in her hands to go pick it up immediately.

Note that this doesn’t necessarily mean she physically had anything in her hands. The phrase is most commonly [*drop everything*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drop+everything), which must originally have referred to just letting go of whatever you had in your hands, but now has the much broader, more generic meaning of stopping whatever you’re currently doing, whether it involves you having something in your hands or not.

Comment: The phrase *drop everything* is metaphorical. The phrase *drop exactly nothing* alludes to the idiom but also has a literal meaning, since the girl is busy doing something when the phone rings, and doing something that requires her to have something in her hand(s). Just to clarify for the OP, Darina

Comment: As a native English-speaker I had trouble parsing the sentence till I read your answer. It feels like it is missing a set of commas: `"She was a girl who, for a ringing phone, dropped exactly nothing."`

Answer (score 12):

Almost all the time a single sentence is, if not insufficient, undesireable when asked to answer 'what does this sentence mean?' Besides that, you left out the second sentence of this quotable.

As others have gleaned, the girl is not willing to drop anything, that is, interrupt anything she is doing in order to answer the phone. *To drop everything* is an idiom meaning to *stop what one is doing to attend to something else.* Here Salinger alludes to the idiom by using an opposite term--'exactly nothing'. The bolded part is a two-sentence paragraph. Both sentences are usually quoted together. Here the girl lets the phone ring until she has finished painting and air drying her left pinky and has otherwise readied herself for the call.

> THERE WERE ninety-seven New York advertising men in the hotel, and, the way they
>   were monopolizing the long-distance lines, the girl in 507 had to wait from noon till
>   almost two-thirty to get her call through. She used the time, though. She read an article
>   in a women's pocket-size magazine, called "Sex Is Fun-or Hell." She washed her comb
>   and brush. She took the spot out of the skirt of her beige suit. She moved the button on
>   her Saks blouse. She tweezed out two freshly surfaced hairs in her mole. When the
>   operator finally rang her room, she was sitting on the window seat and had almost
>   finished putting lacquer on the nails of her left hand.
>
> **She was a girl who for a ringing phone dropped exactly nothing. She looked as if her
>   phone had been ringing continually ever since she had reached puberty.**
>
> With her little lacquer brush, while the phone was ringing, she went over the nail of
>   her little finger, accentuating the line of the moon. She then replaced the cap on the
>   bottle of lacquer and, standing up, passed her left--the wet--hand back and forth
>   through the air. With her dry hand, she picked up a congested ashtray from the window
>   seat and carried it with her over to the night table, on which the phone stood. She sat
>   down on one of the made-up twin beds and--it was the fifth or sixth ring--picked up the
>   phone.

"A Perfect Day for Bananafish"
 – J. D. Salinger
*The New Yorker,* January 31, 1948

Comment: I have not given a second sentence intentionally, so I can figure out what is your sense of this sentence. Looking feeling behind it without giving the author and the book ... Many thanks for telling me what he was thinking, but also want to know what you think and feel as you disregard the author and the book. Excuse my language imperfection, I now begin.

Comment: @darina sentences make more sense in context. Including as much information as possible is as much to your benefit as an act of  courtesy towards users.  Knowing the setting and time period also makes its meaning clearer. This time the  phrase was pretty easy to understand but the next might not be the case.

Comment: +1. Good bit of sleuthing there. It didn’t even occur to me that the sentence might be an extract from a literary piece.

Comment: +1 Context is everything. When I first read the sentence, I envisioned two possibilities: 1. Her phone rings, but she does not allow it to distract her from what she is doing. 2. Her phone simply never rings, and has therefore never dropped anything. The second being a round about way of describing her as homely or ugly. (I'm imagining the inner dialog of some film noir detective.) In context, 2 is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Here ringing phone denotes urgency of a situation with the feeling of "pick it up or you lose" so it means that the girl didn't lose her calm even when in a situation that required her to make a quick choice leaning towards yes than no.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning cannot be gleaned from the information in the sentence. Possibly:

1. She is so intensely focused when performing a task, that she won't even be distracted by a ringing phone.
2. She is so self-centered that she can't even be bothered to stop what she is doing and answer the phone - even though it may be an emergency.
3. She is so conceited that she knows whomever is calling will try again a hundred times until they reach her - so she needn't stop what she is doing.
4. She owes a lot of money and she is avoiding bill collectors.
5. She is a loner and a fugitive - possibly traveling under an assumed name - if the phone is ringing, there is no chance that it's for her, because no one knows where she is.

(Most likely, something akin to #3.)

Comment: I don't think the sense of the sentence is necessarily negative.  The idea that a phone call takes priority over everything else is not necessarily a good one.

Comment: I think the fact that it emphasizes she's not *dropping* anything makes 4 and 5 less likely.

Comment: @HarryJohnston- Back in the olden days, before portable phones and even, answering machines, a ringing telephone was considered second in urgency only to an atomic fallout siren.

Answer (score 1):

I can see only one meaning
She was exactly not the sort of girl who one might find waiting for the phone to ring, ie waiting for friends admirers agents to call because she was confident, sophisticated and not needy or dependant

You should recognise that this statement would probably have been made at a time when the conventional role for a girl was hanging on the arm of a man waiting on his direction and guidance